# C++ - Finding intersection of two ranges

Tags: c++, range, intersection, set-intersection

What is the best way to find the intersection of two ranges in C++? For example, if I have one range as [1...20] inclusive, and another as [13...45] inclusive, I want to get [13...20], as that is the intersection between them.

I thought about using the native set intersection function in C++, but I would first have to convert the range into a set, which would take too much computation time for large values.

Comment: Just write a bunch of `if`s.

Comment: set_intersection takes input and output iterators, so you don't have to convert the range into set but... what exactly is a range?

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
intersection = { std::max(arg1.min, arg2.min), std::min(arg1.max, arg2.max) };
if (intersection.max < intersection.min) {
  intersection.markAsEmpty();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness I would like to add a 'boost answer'.

If you're already using boost, you don't need to write your own code but can take the header-only

```
#include <boost/numeric/interval.hpp>
```

and use the `intersect` function dealing with the type `interval<T>`.

Answer (score 4):

A simple answer in two steps:

- find end values of intersection range
- List item iterate over this range.

say for the range `[l1, r1]`, `[l2, r2]` intersection between them can be calculated as:

```
 if ((r1 < l2) ||  (r2 < l1)) then no intersection exits.
 else l = max(l1, l2) and r = min(r1, r2)
```

just iterate over the range `[l, r]` to get the intersection values.

Answer (score -1):

In 2018, the use of `std::set_intersection` is highly recommended: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection. It doesn't have to be from a `std::set` but the ranges do have to be sorted.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    std::vector<int> v2{        5,  7,  9,10};
    std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());

    std::vector<int> v_intersection;

    std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
                          v2.begin(), v2.end(),
                          std::back_inserter(v_intersection));
    for(int n : v_intersection)
        std::cout << n << ' ';
}
```

Output:

```
5 7
```

Comment: This is not exactly the same and requires far more memory. And uses far more time to compute.

Comment: The OP wanted the intersection of *intervals*, as specified by their lower and upper bounds, not the intersection of sets of objects.