# C++: Intersection Of two ranges

Tags: c++, set, set-intersection

I'm trying to find the intersection of two ranges in C++? For example, if I have one range as [1..14] inclusive, and another as [10..20] inclusive, I want to get [10..14], as that is the intersection between them.

I found a way on SO as follows :

```
intersection = { std::max(arg1.min, arg2.min), std::min(arg1.max, arg2.max) };
if (intersection.max < intersection.min) {
  intersection.markAsEmpty();
}
```

I have few variables as follows :

```
unsigned long long int min1,min2,max1,max2
```

for which I'm trying to find the the intersection. Then I did the following:

```
intersection = { std::max(min1, min2), std::min(max1, max2) };
    if (intersection.max < intersection.min) {
      intersection.markAsEmpty();
    }
```

But this gives the error that unsigned long long int can't be used. How do I use it find the intersection ?

Comment: How is `intersection` defined?

Comment: Blind "Copy and Pasting" is not good. In the code you copied, `intersection` is an object of a class type that obviously has members `max` and `min`.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. Please fill in the surrounding class definitions required to fully compile this code.

Comment: Independent of the anyway required [mcve] I would expect that you provide minimum a link when you are talking about someone else code. Just because something is freely available it doesnt mean that you should not mention the original author

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I found a way on SO as follows :
>
> ```
> intersection = { std::max(arg1.min, arg2.min), std::min(arg1.max, arg2.max) };
> if (intersection.max < intersection.min) {
>   intersection.markAsEmpty();
> }
> ```

Blind "Copy and Pasting" is not good. In the code you [copied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20023538/1621391) (which you should acknowledge), intersection is an object of a class type that obviously has members `max` and `min`.

---

For your own use case:

```
unsigned long long int min1,min2,max1,max2 
......
auto Min = std::max(min1, min2);
auto Max = std::min(max1, max2);
if (Min < Max) {
    // There's an intersection. represented by {Min Max}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

struct range {
    unsigned long long min, max;
};

range intersect(const range& first, const range& second) {
    return {std::max(first.min, second.min), std::min(first.max, second.max)};
}
```

You can call it like, e.g., `intersect({min1, max1}, {min2, max2})`.

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help.

say for the range `[l1, r1]`, `[l2, r2]` intersection between them can be calculated as:

```
 if ((r1 < l2) ||  (r2 < l1)) then no intersection exits.

 else l = max(l1, l2) and r = min(r1, r2)
```

just iterate over the range `[l, r]` to get the intersection values.